# getElementsByTagName("div") not detecting all div's

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I been scraping data from many websites with no problems and using about the same code over and over again with ease. However, A webpage/java at my job that I can't easily work with. Its beefy-er than what I am use too.

The tag structure is as so,

div 
 
div 
 
div 
 
div...div (Opening up the last div I follow it to my destination.)  
 
-div 
 
--div 
---div 
 
----iframe 
 
-----body 
 
------div 
 
-------div 
--------div 
 (etc etc more divs) 
Eventually...
-------------div Id=entity_list 
--------------Span id = name 
--------------Span entityid = 123456798 
Then it closes all back up in reverse order.

If I use the code below after setting up the IE object etc etc. Never had an issue before.

```
 Set Elements = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")
 I = 2

     For Each Element In Elements
            Worksheet.range(I, 2) = Element.ID
            I = I + 1
     Next
```

This code however does not reach the div's inside the (div...div). It will only pickup all the div's on the outside. I'm not sure what type of div this would be considered...embedded div? So I have had no luck trying all the alternative solutions to reaching the "Span Id" and "Span entityid".

I've tried all the variation of getelement(type) for div, span, iframe, body but its as if they don't exist.

I always get errors if I try codes like `Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument`  I think it may be a reference issue but don't know what I need. I don't know if it would even change anything.

There are plenty of java scripts also in the page i'm working with at my job. But they never have cause me any issues before.

Can anyone help me understand how i need to change the code? I'm not an expert.

[Snip of the source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lib8Z.jpg)

After a sleep and a new look I now believe its this "!DOCTYPE html" that is causing the problem. The code doesn't read any type beyond this point. Any ideas?

Comment: dynamically created div's perhaps? created after your vba code runs? though getElementsByTagName should be a live list, but maybe not in vba

Comment: Is there a URL you can share for this and do you have to use Internet Explorer?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the URL is only on my agencies server, I now believe its related to this "!DOCTYPE html"   I was able to sucessfully get the Id of Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

so the solution was pretty simple, I just had to add .contentDocument to access the elements in the Iframe. Once I did that I then look for the element "Span". Never dealt with an Iframe before so that was new to me.

```
    Set Elements= IE.Document.getElementById("iframeid").contentDocument
    I = 1
    For Each Element In Elements.getElementsByTagName("span")

        ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 3) = Element.ID
        ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 2) = Element.innertext
    I = I +1

    Next Element
```

Thanks, I was able to figure it out with a little more clue searching and fresh eyes.